# SpringBoot command-line application with OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a SpringBootApplication that implements CommandLineRunner. We are usign keycloak as our OAuth2 provider with a public client.

We would like to trigger SSO when someone uses the build from a CLI.

ie.

```
$ sampleclitool dosomething
... Redirecting to SSO... waiting for access token... etc..
... SOME_USER_NAME is logged in.
... Doing something!
```

Ive been using Spring Security in other microservices and am trying to figure out how to follow the same "flow".

1. Use the CLI (any command).
2. Check if user is authenticated.
3. If user is not authenticated, open SSO authentication in default browser.
4. If user is authenticated, continue.
5. CLI makes requests to other services (microservices, hosted by me).
6. Authorization header (JWT) is attached to those requests.

The exact trigger for auth isn't important to me, but the end result is that who ever is using the CLI can login to it from the browser, then make request to protected services.

I cannot for the life of me, without some selenium integration, think of a way to achieve this flow. I'm not sure if there are some clever mechanisms in Spring Security that I can hook into.

Using SpringBoot 3.0.1 and WebFlux.